# make[1]: /usr/local/bin/bash: Command not found

Tags: macos, bash, makefile

I cleaned up my mac and `make` stopped working as *it worked before*. There is `/bin/bash` but `make` started looking for it in `/usr/local/bin/bash`. Makefile is correct, something is definitely wrong with my paths. Please help.

```
NYC-JDOE-MBP:jdk9 jdoe$ make
make[1]: /usr/local/bin/bash: Command not found
make[1]: /usr/local/bin/bash: Command not found
make[1]: /usr/local/bin/bash: Command not found
/Users/jdoe/dev/jdk9/make/common/Modules.gmk:65: *** No source files found for BUILD_GENMODULESLIST.  Stop.
make: Nothing to be done for 'default'.
NYC-JDOE-MBP:jdk9 jdoe$ which bash
/bin/bash
```

Comment: What is the value of your `SHELL` environment variable?

Comment: "Makefile is correct" — I won't be so sure about it. At least you need to show us what's in your Makefile that's trying to access bash, because `make` executes commands with `/bin/sh` by default.

Comment: NYC-JDOE-MBP:jdk9 jdoe $ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

Comment: Makefile worked yesterday before I decided to cleanup. It's openjdk9 Makefile so it's 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

create symlink for bash to local folder.

`ln -s /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bash`